# How to detect aspect ratio of monitor?

Tags: shell, monitors, resolution, display

How do you detect the `aspect ratio` of your monitor? I tried:

```
root@malou-laptop:/home/liv# xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 1680 x 1050
default connected 1680x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1680x1050      60.0* 
   1280x1024      61.0  
   1280x800        0.0  
   1024x768       61.0  
   800x600        61.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

And figured out that you can compute it by `1680:1050 = 1.6 = 16:10`, or by checking the [Display resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution#Computer_monitors) list on Wikipedia.

But is there a command that nicely outputs this? I already tried `lshw` and `hardinfo`, with no luck.

Comment: I modified my answer to show how you can script this using the list from wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

You found the command yourself, you just need to parse it. For example:

```
$ xrandr -q | grep -Po 'current\s*\d+\s*x\s*\d+' | awk '{print $1/$3}'
```

The regular expression looks for `current`, then 0 or more white space characters (`\s*`), then one or more digits (`\d+`) followed by `\s*`, then `x`, then `\s*` and finally more digits. The `\K` simply discards anything that was matched up to that point:

```
$ xrandr -q | grep -Po 'current\s*\K\d+\s*x\s*\d+'
1680 x 1050
```

So, you pass that to `gawk` which will split into fields on whitespace and print the result of the second field divided by the fourth.

---

A better way is to get the [list from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution#Computer_monitors) and simply paste it into a text file (make sure the tabs between the fields are copied correctly):

```
$ cat resolutions.txt
VGA 4:3 640 480 00.02   n/a
SVGA    4:3 800 600 00.17   01.03
WSVGA   ~17:10  1024    600 00.31   02.25
XGA 4:3 1024    768 05.53   18.69
XGA+    4:3 1152    864 00.87   01.55
WXGA    16:9    1280    720 01.51   01.54
WXGA    5:3 1280    768 n/a 01.54
WXGA    16:10   1280    800 04.25   12.97
SXGA– (UVGA)    4:3 1280    960 00.72   00.72
SXGA    5:4 1280    1024    10.66   07.49
HD  ~16:9   1360    768 02.36   02.28
HD  ~16:9   1366    768 17.19   19.14
SXGA+   4:3 1400    1050    00.18   n/a
WXGA+   16:10   1440    900 07.60   06.61
HD+ 16:9    1600    900 06.82   03.82
UXGA    4:3 1600    1200    00.53   n/a
WSXGA+  16:10   1680    1050    10.26   03.66
FHD 16:9    1920    1080    25.04   05.09
WUXGA   16:10   1920    1200    03.65   01.11
QWXGA   16:9    2048    1152    00.13   n/a
WQHD    16:9    2560    1440    00.72   00.36
WQXGA   16:10   2560    1600    00.19   n/a
    3:4 768 1024    n/a 01.93
    16:9    1093    614 n/a 00.63
    ~16:9   1311    737 n/a 00.35
Other               01.29   07.25
```

Now, use that file to get the value you need:

```
$ grep -Po 'current\s*\K\d+\s*x\s*\d+' a | sed 's/ *x */ /' | 
    while read x y; do 
     grep "$x" resolutions.txt | grep "$y" | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'; 
  done 
16:10
```

Finally, make this into a little script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## The location of the file with the resolutions
RESOLUTIONS="$HOME/resolutions.txt" 

xrandr -q | grep -Po 'current\s*\K\d+\s*x\s*\d+' | sed 's/ *x */ /' | 
while read x y; do 
    grep "$x" "$RESOLUTIONS" | grep "$y" | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'; 
done
```

Save the script somewhere in your $PATH and then run it to get the resolution:

```
$ get_resolution.sh
16:10
```

Comment: This math won't actually always work, e.g., consider a monitor with a resolution of 720×480. That is 4:3. Probably. Could also be 16:9. Depends on the display.

Comment: @derobert yeah, that's why I added the method that parses the wikipedia list.

Comment: 720×480 is missing from that list... probably because it's not really a computer resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for some script, not only for your curiosity you can sed/awk xrandr output for this value and calculate it by least common multiple algorithm.

However, for ex. for 16:10 it will be 8:5 (it's mathematically correct, but not how we are used to. So it can be simpler to match it in some kind of associative table.